Uniform blooming times of two flowers
Say there are two different flower seeds in a garden, a red and a purple one.
The purple flower will blossom within the next 30 days and bloom for 9 days, whereas the red flower will blossom within the next 30 days too but be in bloom for 12 days. What's the probability that both flowers will be in bloom at the same time?
My approach is to do it visually, compute the favorable area divided by the total area.
Total area = $30\times30$
The favorable area would be the Total area minus two triangles in which the blooms don't overlap, so:
Favorable = $30\times30 - (21^2 \div 2) - (18^2 \div 2)$
This yields:
$P = \frac{517.5}  {900} = \frac{23}{40}$
Can anyone confirm this or tell me where I'm wrong?
Somebody else said the solution should be 169 / 360

It looks like they gave you the probability for them to not bloom at the same time and wrongly calculated it using 22 and 19 instead of 21 and 18.

I agree with your answer. The first step is to clearly define the sample space. Here, we are given that both flowers will blossom within the next $30$ days; of course, we will assume that the blossom times are uniformly distributed within this time period. Therefore, we may take the sample space as $\Omega = [0, 30] \times [0, 30]$, where the first factor specifies the blossom time (in days) of the red flower, and the second factor specifies the blossom time (in days) of the purple flower. We have $m (\Omega) = 30^2$.
Now, in order for both flowers to be in bloom at the same time, the time that the purple flower blossoms must be later than $9$ days earlier than the red flower blossoms and less than $12$ days after the red flower blossoms. This defines a hexagonal region, call it $S$, in $\Omega$, whose complement is two isosceles triangles, one with leg $18$ and the other with leg $21$. Therefore,
$$m (S) = \frac{1}{2} (18^2 + 21^2)$$
Then
$$P = 1 - \frac{m (S)}{m (\Omega)} = 1 - \frac{\frac{1}{2} (18^2 + 21^2)}{30^2}$$
$$= 1 - \frac{17}{40} = \boxed{\frac{23}{40}}$$
as you calculated.

that's nice, thinking about the sample space makes it even clearer.
