Uniform distribution of blooming flowers

A gardener is eagerly waiting for his two favorite flowers to bloom. The purple flower will blossom at some point uniformly at random in the next 20 days and be in bloom for exactly 4 days. Independent of the purple flower, the red flower will blossom at some point uniformly at random in the next 20 days and be in bloom for exactly 8 days. Compute the probability that both flowers will simultaneously be in bloom at some point in time.

I sketched out the possibilities on a graph and came up the the following:
$$ \frac{400-(\frac{1}{2} \times 12 \times 16)-(\frac{1}{2} \times 12 \times 16)}{400} = \frac {13}{25} $$
Is my approach and answer correct? Thank you.

It seems you're not considering the effect of one of them blooming near the start or end of the twenty days. If the purple flower blooms on the first day,  the red flower would have to bloom on one of the first four. If violet blooms on the second, red can bloom on any of the first 5, and so forth, until violet blooming on the ninth day gives red 12 days to bloom. That 12 day possible in-bloom overlaps up through violet blooming on the 17th day. On the 18th, 19th, and 20th days red has 11, 10 and 9 days.
This assumes that simultaneous blooming means that red and violet are each in bloom at some time in a day, which your work seems to assume. The phrasing of the question you quoted says "at some point in time," which implies a different definition. That definition would mean that the blooming overlap could be very small and I think it makes the problem easier. For the first 8 days, Reds possible overlap duration increases to 12. It stays at 12 for 8 more days, then declines to 8 over the last 4. The probability that Violet blooms in the first interval is 8/20. The average value of the overlap period by red is 8 days and the probability that it's the right 8  is 1/20 so the overall probability of being in bloom at the same point in time is 64/400 for the first interval. The answers for the other two can be found the same way. The overall answer is not 13/25.

I redid the sketch and found the new triangles to have a dimension of $12$ units $\times$ $16$ units. The final probability I'm getting is $\frac{13}{25}$. Is this right?

Can you describe your approach, and include your diagrams?

Using the approach from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4969779/uniform-blooming-times-of-two-flowers, I got the following:
$ P = 1 - \frac{\frac{1}{2} \times (16^2 + 12^2)}{20^2} = \frac{1}{2}$.
Does this seem right?

It is right. That's what I got.
